# How to efficiently retrieve value of an attribute at a given time in Django Reversions?

Tags: django, django-reversion

I am currently using django-reversion to track a model `Account` which has a field `total_spent`.

Overtime this field gets updated whenever an accounts spends money. My goal is to retrieve the value of `total_spent` between X and Y, which are both datetime instances.

How can I do so efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have something like this: given you have a Django model and two time fields, get their elapsed time difference:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def total_spent(self):
        return self.end_time - self.start_time
```

and then use **total_spent** as yet another property of that model.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to know the value in both instances. For that you have to store `total_spent` every time it updates.